# Relocating and renaming file C++ using stdio.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stdio

I am trying to rename a file with the **rename()** function of *stdio.h* and it works but the problem is that it can only rename files located in the folder of the current project, I would like to be able to select a directory and if it is possible to change it from location in the process.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    bool verifier;
    char oldName[] = "text.txt";
    char newName[] = "newText.txt";
    verifier = rename(oldName, newName);

    if (!verifier)
    {
        std::cout << "The file has been succesfully renamed\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "There was a problem renaming the file\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You have to specify all path to file i guess. eg 'C:\\SOisbestdotcom\\text.txt' or in linux '/SOisbestdotcom/test.txt'

Comment: Or at least a relative one `..\..\folder\file.ext`.

Comment: You can use `errno` to find what was error.

Comment: I thought that but it doesn't work at all because it starts to search for a file with the name of the directory

Comment: As @Vilx- mention, you can move to previous folder in tree with `..\\`

Comment: Check your working directory using `getcwd`. FYI, \ should be \\ (escape char).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the root directory path is the location which the executable is running in. If you want to access another folder above our outside that location, you can use an absolute path (ie C:/path/to/old.txt).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char oldName[] = "C:\\path\\to\\your\\proj\\text.txt"; // char oldName[] = "old.txt";
   char newName[] = "C:\\test\\output\\folder\\new.txt"; // char newName[] = "newText.txt";
   bool verifier = rename(oldName, newName);

   if (!verifier)
   {
      std::cout << "The file has been succesfully renamed\n";
   }
   else
   {
      std::cout << "There was a problem renaming the file\n";
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem I had was a very strange one, when you put the directory with this / it works but with this \ one t doesn´t.

Comment: Ermm... you weren't writing it like this, were you? `char oldName[] = "C:\path\to\your\proj\text.txt";` Because remember that the C++ compiler processes the strings and turns things like `\n` into newlines, `\t` into tabs, etc. Therefore, the correct way to write a path is: `char oldName[] = "C:\\path\\to\\your\\proj\\text.txt";` The double backslashes get converted to single backslashes by the compiler.

Comment: Yes, I was writing it like that. Thank you very much! I have implemented more functions now.

Comment: thanks @vilx for the correction, I updated my answer =)